# Who was the first to use Softmax to model decision making?

Tags: computational-modeling, decision-making

Softmax is a mathematical function frequently used to model probabilistic choice between multiple alternatives associated with different values, e.g. two arms in a bandit task; See for example [1] and [2].

Where was this method first applied?

*[1] Shteingart, Hanan, Tal Neiman, and Yonatan Loewenstein. "The role of first impression in operant learning." Journal of Experimental Psychology: General 142.2 (2013): 476.‏*

*[2] Egelman, David M., Christophe Person, and P. Read Montague. "A computational role for dopamine delivery in human decision-making." Journal of Cognitive Neuroscience 10.5 (1998): 623-630.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Sutton and Barto](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf):

> The term soft-max for the action selection rule ... is due to [Bridle (1990)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/195-training-stochastic-model-recognition-algorithms-as-networks-can-lead-to-maximum-mutual-information-estimation-of-parameters).
>   This rule appears to have been first proposed by [Luce (1959)](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1960-03588-000)